# Password reset token in Python Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to generate a password reset token for a User model that I have with Google App Engine. Apparently we're not allowed to use Django that easily with GAE, so the raw code for the Django method for generating tokens is:

```
def _make_token_with_timestamp(self, user, timestamp):
    # timestamp is number of days since 2001-1-1.  Converted to
    # base 36, this gives us a 3 digit string until about 2121
    ts_b36 = int_to_base36(timestamp)

    # By hashing on the internal state of the user and using state
    # that is sure to change (the password salt will change as soon as
    # the password is set, at least for current Django auth, and
    # last_login will also change), we produce a hash that will be
    # invalid as soon as it is used.
    # We limit the hash to 20 chars to keep URL short
    key_salt = "django.contrib.auth.tokens.PasswordResetTokenGenerator"

    # Ensure results are consistent across DB backends
    login_timestamp = user.last_login.replace(microsecond=0, tzinfo=None)

    value = (unicode(user.id) + user.password +
            unicode(login_timestamp) + unicode(timestamp))
    hash = salted_hmac(key_salt, value).hexdigest()[::2]
    return "%s-%s" % (ts_b36, hash)
```

Python is not my language of expertise, so I'll need some help writing a custom method similar to the one above. I just have a couple questions. First, what is the purpose of the timestamp? And Django has its own User system, while I'm using a simple custom User model of my own. What aspects from the above code will I need to retain, and which ones can I do away with?

Comment: Wow, that function is full of issues. For a start `key_salt` isn't a salt, it's a (not very) secret key, and does pretty much nothing to enhance the security of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the [`check_token`](https://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py)-method looks like this:

```
def check_token(self, user, token):
    """
    Check that a password reset token is correct for a given user.
    """
    # Parse the token
    try:
        ts_b36, hash = token.split("-")
    except ValueError:
        return False

    try:
        ts = base36_to_int(ts_b36)
    except ValueError:
        return False

    # Check that the timestamp/uid has not been tampered with
    if not constant_time_compare(self._make_token_with_timestamp(user, ts), token):
        return False

    # Check the timestamp is within limit
    if (self._num_days(self._today()) - ts) > settings.PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS:
        return False

    return True
```

- first the timestamp part of the token is converted back to integer
- then a new token is generated using that timestamp and compared to the old token.
   Note that when generating a token the timestamp of the last login is one of the parameters used to calculate the hash. That means that after a user login the old token would become invalid, which makes sense for a password reset token.
- lastly a check is performed to see if the token hasn't alerady timed out.

it's a fairly simple process, and also fairly secure. If you wanted to use the reset-system to break into an account, you'd have to know the user's password and last login timestamp to calculate the hash. And if you knew that wouldn't need to break into the account...

So if you want to make a system like that, it's important when generating the hast to use parameters that are not easy to guess, and of course to use a good, salted hash function. Django [uses sha1](https://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/utils/crypto.py), using other `hashlib` digests would of course be easily possible.

Another way would be to generate a random password reset token and store it in the database, but this potentially wastes a lot of space as the token-column would probably be empty for most of the users.